# ActiveMQ persistent messages (durable queue) configuration problem?

Tags: c#, activemq-classic, persistent

Let me first describe the way I am planning to use activemq for my service.

The service provides API for its clients and guarantees to notify anybody interested in the changes happened to its data. For example if new user is created, every API user should be able to be notified about it and query for new information if they want to (or handle the notification any other way). To implement these notifications I use activemq. Notifications are sent as persistent messages to the associated topics, e.g. `"Service.User"` and therefore everyone who wants to stay notified about new users can simply implement the durable consumer to receive messages from that topic.

There are not many topics I need, but the volume of messages might be quite high - I am expecting around 100-200k notification per day for the very beginning and be able to increase this number drastically when deploying to production.

Having implemented the above scenario I seem to face a problem of limitations of some sort.
The service is developed in `C#.Net` and `Apache.NMS` and **ActiveMQ** is installed on **Windows Server** machine.
I didn't have time to optimize my code and I do create a new connection/session/producer for every single notification sent (since there is not support in C# for `pooledconnectionfactory` yet) . But it's not an issue since for the moment I am not concerned about this sort of performance.

The problem I have that when running my functional tests it seems I am not able to send messages to activemq once it reachs around 20k of messages. It just hangs and results in a timeout for my transaction (40 secs). It gets resolved when I remove all topics' messages at http://localhost:8161/admin/topics.jsp admin page.

Can you please point me to the right actviemq configuration I should use for my case?

What can be the reason of the problem I am facing?

Any overall suggestions are welcome as well!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds as though you are running into [Producer Flow Control](http://activemq.apache.org/producer-flow-control.html) in action.  If you intend to keep large numbers of persistent messages around then you will probably need to configure the broker with more space otherwise it will throttle the producer until some consumer comes along to consume the messages and free up space.  See the link above for some more info.

Comment: Hi Tim, you're correct - that was caused by FlowControl limit. How do I configure the queue if I need to store large number of messages? The consumers are durable that means that one can register today and go down for a month and when getting back online expect all messages for the topic. Does it mean I should set the high limits in the config for storing the messages and that's it? Another question is - how can I remove the messages - let's say after 1 month?

Comment: You might want to instead look at virtual topics for this application instead of durable subscriptions as the durable subscriber model in JMS sort of sucks. See http://activemq.apache.org/virtual-destinations.html